# TypeError in Python Euler's Method Simulation

Tags: python, list, int

I am trying to simulate Euler's method for a simple SIR-type model in Python.  To do so I am doing the following:

1. Building functions for each differential equation that determine the next value of the solution (through Euler's method).
2. Initializing blank lists to hold the value of each equation at the given time step.
3. Running a for-loop to find the next value of each value in the equation's list.

When I do this, I am receiving a TypeError as follows:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'list'
```

I tried print-statement debugging to make sure that my inputs to the function (in this case the function s_next), are all ints and floats (which they are), but I am still receiving this error.  My code is below.

```
import numpy as np

#Parameters
mu = 0.56
epsilon = 0.01 #* time_step
z = 0.05 * 0.21 #(percent with aids * aids death rate)
p = 0.25 #* time_step
q = 0.05 #* time_step #Assumption
beta = 0.01

#dS Function
def s_next(S, P, I, time_step):
    return S + time_step * ((S * epsilon) + (q * P) - (p * S) - (beta * S * 
                             I))


#dP Function
def p_next(S, P, I, time_step):
    return P + time_step * ((p * S) - (q * P) - (mu * (beta * P * I)))

#dI Function
def i_next(S, P, I, time_step):
    return I + time_step * ((beta * S * I) + (mu * beta * P * I) - (z * I))

#Arrays For Each Compartment
time_values = np.arange(0, 100, 0.1)

s = [0] * len(time_values)
p = [0] * len(time_values)
i = [0] * len(time_values)

s[0] = 56400
p[0] = 1000
i[0] = 10575

#For Loop For Array Iteration
for increment in range(1, len(time_values)):
    s_current_value = int(s[increment - 1])
    p_current_value = int(p[increment - 1])
    i_current_value = int(i[increment - 1])

    print('s_current_type', type(s_current_value))
    print('p_current_type', type(p_current_value))
    print('i_current_type', type(i_current_value))

    s_next_value = s_next(s_current_value, p_current_value, i_current_value, 
                          0.1)
    p_next_value = p_next(s_current_value, p_current_value, i_current_value, 
                          0.1)
    i_next_value = i_next(s_current_value, p_current_value, i_current_value, 
                          0.1)

    s[increment] = s_next_value
    p[increment] = p_next_value
    i[increment] = i_next_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the variable name `p` twice. Once, at the top of your code and then again when you initialise your lists:

```
p = 0.25 #* time_step

#.....

p = [0] * len(time_values)
```

Therefore, in your `s_next` function, when you try and do `(p * S)`, it thinks `p` is your list rather than the value 0.25 which is probably what you want it to be.

The solution would be to rename either the list or the variable

Comment: Thank you that makes so much more sense now!

Comment: @Howsikan No problem. If an answer helped solve your problem then don't forget to [vote and/or accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me @DavidG, but I don't think I have enough karma to vote yet, I will when I do!

Comment: @Howsikan You can click the little tick below the up and down arrows which "accepts" the answer. It is up to you to decide which answer/or if any answer solved your question